# Layout where the logo is exactly in the center and two icons of different size are at the left and right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to duplicate a very basic layout where the logo is exactly in the center and two icons of different size are at the left and right of the header bar.

What I need is (1) but what I get is (2):

[image]

```css
.showcase header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <div class="toggle">toggle</div>
    <h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>
    <div class="booknow">averyverylongbooknow</div>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) along with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). What I did below is to give every column `1/3` of the parent's width, then position them as I want inside that given espace.

```css
.showcase header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;   
  justify-content: center; 
}

.booknow { 
  display: flex;   
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <div class="toggle">toggle</div>
    <h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>
    <div class="booknow">averyverylongbooknow</div>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

```css
header > * {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this make you to Get a result
`justify-content: space-around;`

```css
showcase header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to comment this too xD. I think this will solve his problem too.

Comment: Except it doesn't output what he wanted as you can see here https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/JjpzevM. Please use the HTML he gave to make a runnable snippet.

Comment: Yes that only i will give you to solve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).